# Rails OR SQL solution : How to find all unique participants in a forum topic's thread

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Given a Topic has many Posts

And a Post belongs to a User

I want a topics participants (users) without duplicate users and in order of the first poster coming first in the result set and the last poster last.

I'd like to know how I could achieve that either in plain SQL or using Rails has_many method.

I tried

```
class Topic
  has_many :posts, -> { order('created_at ASC') }
  has_many :participants, -> { uniq }, through: :posts, source: :user
end
```

But it seems @topic.participants doesn't come in the order expected. Adding an explicit order to the has_many is invalid as well.

```
has_many :participants, -> { order('posts.created_at ASC').uniq }, through: :posts, source: :user
```

I also tried this from the User side like so

```
User.joins(:posts).where('posts.topic_id' => 1).order('posts.created_at ASC').uniq
```

But that doesn't work either.

I'd love to know how to solve this both via Rails and/or SQL statement.

Comment: What if first poster is also the last poster?

Comment: yes my sql skills are not the best but i did think this ambiguity could be the source of the problem. What I want is the first instance of any poster to be included but any repeat instances to be left out. So to answer your question, the first poster would be returned but not when they were the last poster.

Comment: You need to specify a DISTINCT there somewhere. Doing `uniq` in app code is suboptimal

Answer (score 0):

I think it will work if models and query look like this(not tested)

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :participants, through: :posts, source: :user
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
  scope :sorted, ->{order('created_at ASC')}
end
```

Rails:

```
topic.posts.sorted.includes(:user).map(&:user).uniq
```

SQL:

```
SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` IN (
  SELECT `posts`.user_id FROM `posts` WHERE `posts`.`topic_id` = 1 ORDER BY created_at ASC
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a sample Rails application to test that the following works:

```
class Topic
  # change below:
  # has_many :posts, -> { order('created_at ASC') }
  # into:
  has_many :posts, -> { order(created_at: :asc) }
  has_many :participants, -> { uniq }, through: :posts, source: :user
end
```